# How to enable swap accounting for memory cgroup in Archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, memory, swap, cgroups

On my Archlinux box I want to limit some applications to a smaller amount of memory using [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt). Since I use swap, I need to account memory+swap. How can I enable swap accounting?

Comment: From the document you linked to: `memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes  # set/show limit of memory+Swap usage` - does this not work for you?

Comment: @Wieland I don't have this file. As the doc says, it's only present when swap is accounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch Linux' kernel has the swap accounting disabled by default (cf. [the kernel config file](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/config?h=packages/linux#n147)). You can enable it by booting with `swapaccount=1` in your kernel cmdline (cf. [the kernels Kconfig documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig?id=f6187769dae48234f3877df3c4d99294cc2254fa#n988).

Comment: Since it's disabled by default, I wonder what the downsides are?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can edit

> /etc/default/grub

and replace the line

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

by

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="swapaccount=1"

Then run update-grub [optional], and reboot the server.

find more tricks in http://kencochrane.net/blog/2013/08/the-docker-guidebook/#remove-all-docker-images