# How to enable swap accounting for memory cgroup?

Tags: grub, swap, suse, cgroups

I am trying to enable swap accounting for cgroup on SLES 11 SP4 system.

[From This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147158/how-to-enable-swap-accounting-for-memory-cgroup-in-archlinux) I have found that by editing /etc/default/grub file, I can enable swap accounting.

But on my system I don't have /etc/default/grub file or any config file to configure default grub parameter.